# Git - how to work on two separate branches in two separate folders and push to common origin without problems

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I currently have two versions of my software in two separate branches. One version has major changes (renamed some folders, renamed some files, removed a lot of files).

I wish to be able to work on both versions - e.g. do a bugfix in master, push it to origin, maybe merge it into the other branch.

I just tried to do this, and got a bit confused. I did the bug fix in master, and pushed it. I pulled master into the other branch folder. This also seemed to merge. I pushed the result.

Now, if I make another change in the master folder, and try to push all branches, I get complaints "Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote counterpart" relating to the other branch.

I then tried to pull the other branch into my master folder, but that did a horrible merge, and I ended up with the wrong branch. I think I have recovered from that, but I still can't push from my master folder.

Obviously I am misunderstanding the correct way of working with TortoiseGit, can anyone advise me how I should be proceeding?

Results of `git branch -vv`

```
in master folder:
  CodeFirst             3b4d37b [origin/CodeFirst] Show 25 entries in DataTables if the screen is big enough.
  CodeFirstWebFramework be03722 Added DocumentMemo to report fields.
  SilverstreamMerge     778b791 default.js merge
* master                6c1254c [origin/master] Prevent Download button appearing twice in reports.

in branch (CodeFirstWebFramework) folder
* CodeFirstWebFramework 08b9117 Merge branch 'master' of //router/var/svn/AccountServer into CodeFirstWebFramework
  master                b7994b3 [origin/master: behind 2] Validate Schedule.RepeatFrequency

in origin (upstream repo on another machine)
  CodeFirst             3b4d37b Show 25 entries in DataTables if the screen is big enough.
  CodeFirstWebFramework 08b9117 Merge branch 'master' of //router/var/svn/AccountServer into CodeFirstWebFramework
  SilverstreamMerge     778b791 default.js merge
* master                6c1254c Prevent Download button appearing twice in reports.
```

I think I am (incorrectly) expecting the `pull` command to copy all revisions of all branches from the upstream repo into the local repo. Is there a command to do this?

Comment: Can you execute `git branch -vv` in your repository and paste the results?

Comment: There shouldn't be a problem merging master into your feature branch in terms of damaging master in any way so the way you describe it should work out just fine. It would seem there is something you did that think was inconsequential, thus either not remembering that you did it or at least not mentioning it here, that actually had bigger consequences and thus placed you where you're currently at, with a master that can't be pushed.

Comment: Have you tried executing `git log origin/master..master` and `git log master..origin/master` to see what you haven't applied, does it make sense?

Comment: Have executed all the suggested commands - see question for `git branch -vv`. `git log master..origin/master` produced no output.

Comment: As you can see from the output, in one local clone you're updated with master, in the other you're behind. This is a typical problem with multiple clones, they will each separately have to be updated and maintained. Look at Mark Adelsberges answer below and learn about worktrees, this will alleviate some of the pain of having multiple branches checked out simultaneously.

Comment: Ok, the question now becomes how do I update the clone so it is no longer behind (ideally without switching branches).

Comment: @NikkiLocke - Why "without switching branches"?  You can always switch back.  (If you're worried about losing uncommitted changes, use `git stash` before you start and `git stash pop` once you're back on the correct branch.)  If you switch branches, you can just `pull` each one (or `fetch` once and `merge` each remote ref into the corresponding local).  To do it without switching branches (and without making any mistakes) is quite tedious

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you have two clones of the repo - one checked out to `master` and one checked out to `some_branch`.  That is the more "obvious" way to keep two branches around locally, and there's not necessarily anything wrong with it, but it does mean you have two local sets of branch refs.

If that's the case, you might want to consider `git work-tree` as an option.  With this you could attach a second working tree to a single local repo, so each tree could be checked out to a different branch without duplicating other aspects of the repository (like the ref list).  This could make it simpler to keep everything in sync.

As far as what happened in your situation... it doesn't seem obvious to me; knowing the exact commands you used might help.  In general I can say that when the `push` fails with that error message, a `pull` might help (or, if you're worried about doing that without knowing *why* first, a `fetch` and then examine the differences between the local and remote ref for each branch).

Answer (score 1):

There is a Git method called "cherry pick": if you have a commit in a branch you can apply this commit on another branch. Try to use this, but if the commit includes files that don't exist because they have been renamed than I think this method will not work (and I think there is no solution that can work).

Switch to the branch where you want to apply a commit, open your repository's log in TortoiseGit (show log in the TortoiseGit context menu). In the top left corner choose all branches or the branch where you have applied the commit. Find the commit, right click on it, cherry pick this commit. If succeeds don't forget to push :)
[image]

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of cherry pick - but, as far as I can see, it doesn't do what I want. I usually use rebase for this part of the process. But my problem is how to get my master folder into a state where it is allowed to push to the remote - I want to somehow update the other branch in the master folder with the git information from the remote, without altering the source files in the folder, or doing any merges or rebases.